# NHibernate - Get Categories, Count and Top 5 Items in Each Category

Tags: nhibernate

In my application I have many articles, each of which belongs to one or more categories. On my homepage I would like to list all categories with the total number of articles it contains underneath which I would like to show the top X article descriptions (based on when the article was posted). It would looks something like the following

```
Home Decorating (105)
- How to fix Windows
- How to fix Curtains
- How to fix Doors
- How to fix Counter tops
- How to fix sofas
```

My mappings are pretty simple and can be traversed either from the article or the category - both of which have nhibernate mapping files.

I can do this pretty easily from a stored proc, but for learning purposes would like to accomplish this via NHibernate and was wondering if there is an efficient way to do this or if i'm always going to end up with multiple queries.

Does anyone know how this could be accomplished via NHibernate?

**Update**
Here are the mappings:

```
<class name="MyProj.News.Category, MyProj.News">
    <id name="Id" column="ID"/>

    <bag name="Articles" table="Category_Article" lazy="true">
        <key column="CATEGORY_ID"/>
        <many-to-many class="MyProj.News.Article, MyProj.News" column="Article_ID"/>
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="MyProj.News.Article, MyProj.News">
    <id name="id" column="ID"/>
    <!-- inverse end -->
    <bag name="categories" table="Category_Article" inverse="true" lazy="true">
        <key column="ARTICLE_ID"/>
        <many-to-many class="MyProj.News.Category, MyProj.News" column="CATEGORY_ID"/>
    </bag>
</class>
```

Comment: Can you post your mappings and/or table structure? Also, when you say you want to accomplish this with 'NHibernate', would hql be acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but with some SQL magic. I'll not give a complete solution here, but hopefully you'll figure this out.

For count, it's best to add new `Count` property to your `Category` entity and [map it using `formula`](http://ayende.com/blog/3936/nhibernate-mapping-property) with subquery "`select count(*) from Items ...`".

For top 5 items, you'll either need to modify your Category.Items collection mapping or create another one, i.e. Category.TopItems. Then add [`where` mapping](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping) to filter your result to top 5 rows (for SQL Server you can use something like "`row_number() over(order by DateAdded) < 5`". There are equivalents for other databases for sure, too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could consider an alternate approach; rather than trying to create your entire resultset in one query - how about sending multiple queries in  a single round-trip?

NHibernate has support for this in the form of [multi-queries](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-16-improving-performance#16%282E%297%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Multi_Query), [multi-criteria](http://ayende.com/blog/2413/nhibernate-multi-criteria), and [futures](http://ayende.com/blog/3979/nhibernate-futures). You could then assemble the results of these smaller queries into a form that makes sense for display.

I should note that hql has recently had [support for skip and take](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/04/support-for-skip-and-take-in-hql.html) constructs added, which you could likely use to construct your top(x) in each category query.

Answer (score 0):

Even with straight SQL, it's not easily done in an efficient manner.  To solve this problem in the proper manner, you should be caching the count of articles on the category entity.  Any time you can eliminate unnecessary queries to the database, you should.

Doing this is simple enough.  When a new article is added, or one is removed, trigger an update for the total count on the category.

This solution is all around the best approach because now the total count of articles exists on the category entity.  You can then simply make one call to get the list of top n articles for the category.